# Where does the TODO convention come from?

Tags: coding-style, convention, todo

I suspect this question has been asked before, but it's not easy to Google for.

I am a fairly new coder and I see a lot of code, in a lot of different languages, with comments beginning "TODO".

Questions:

- Is there a practical reason why people write TODO in all these different languages, or is it merely a convention?
- If the latter, where did the convention come from?

I can see why it's useful to be able to grep for TODO, I'm just curious about the history behind it.

Comment: I used to think I was the only one who did this until I saw it in someone else's code and was surprised. One of the reasons I like TODO is that in spanish, todo means everything, and since I always use TODO for all unfinished tasks in my code, I can make sure I capture everything

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Programming is a world-wide activity; conventions to help smooth the process of working with people who are not native speakers of each other's languages are worth their weight in gold. `TODO`, `XXX` and `FIXME` are often highlighted by IDEs, which provides an excellent incentive to stick with these options.

- `XXX` suggests a danger or hazard that maintenance programmers must be aware of;
- `FIXME` insinuates that something is wrong with some implentation which needs to be changes;
- `TODO` explains shortcomings that would be nice to address.

Comment: TODO because it is common for people to maintain [to-do lists](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Todo_list#Task_list) -- _things to do_. XXX because it is visually so much denser than usual text.

Comment: In spanish TODO means EVERYTHING so it can be confusing for begginers

Answer (score 4):

TODO means "to do". Something that someone will need **to do**. Just guessing, but could this guess be wrong?

Comment: Sure, but I just wondered whether it had any other significance (e.g. whether IDEs provided a programmatic way to handle them, as @sarnold's answer suggests).

Comment: But why *TODO* and not *To-do* or *ToDo*?

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the comments about grepping, editor/IDE identification etc. I would think that a big reason as to why `TODO` became the standard, instead of say `todo` or `ToDo`, is simply that `TODO` is a big todo.

Answer (score 1):

Just a quick follow up to the original answer:
This feature is mainly a reference and you'll find it in Frameworks if there are items that aren't detrimental to the code still running, but that the developers would like to address.

The nice thing about modern IDE's, for example I use JetBrains PHPStorm, they actually highlifht TODOs and place them into a Toolbar for your entire project so you can see all the TODOs for all your files differentiated by their directory and file name.

Anyway, just thought this may add further light as to why you may see it throughout code.